# Using php: Search for a folder based on user's input and display contents

Tags: php, search

We have a folder structure with pdf documents in each folder. The folders and contents change on a daily basis and are too numerous to simply list. We want to give a user the ability to enter a folder name and as a result receive a list of hyperlinks to the pdfs within the searched folder.

We have had a go with glob () and can display tge contents of a specific folder but can't figure out how to search for the folder entered by the user.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to:

1 - Create a page in php, which you will access with AJAX, to the user get help in typing the name of folder.
Like in this example with names:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

2 - Then we will create a scandir function, that will get all the subdirectories and add it to the array, that will be given back to the user, with a link to it.

3 - On user click (select the directory) you will pass the $_GET or $_POST parameter that will hold the name of the folder.

4 - Then you need to write the code as:

$path = **DIR** . "directory/" . $_GET['folder_name'];

5 - Use the $path var into your glob, to open the folder and list all items in it.

Dont forget to make if/else statements, to check if this folders exist and that the user is in the right folder, otherwise send it to error page... make secure websites =D

Hope it helped =)

I Will add here the comment code, for easier view =D

```
<form method="get" action="" id="link">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="generate_link(this.value)">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
function generate_link(value) {
    var form = document.getElementById('link');
    form.action = "index.php?folder=" + value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I don't understand step two. We don't want to present a list of subdirectories for the user to click. If a user enters A in the search box we want to display the contents of folder A, same with B, C , D etc

Comment: @AnjamSohail even easier so =)
<form method="get" action="" id="link">
 <input type="text" onkeyup="generate_link(this.value)">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
function generate_link(value) {
 var form = document.getElementById('link');
 form.action = "index.php?folder=" + value;
}
</script>

Create a form, with input. When user writes something, javascript will generate link to page, as $_GET['folder'] = folder name. 
So all you need to do is take this GET parameter and add it to the directory path.